# Need to show and edit data, on selected item in Treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, treeview

New to WPF,C#,.Net here!

I'm working on a user interface to manage user privileges. I've decided to use a Treeview, witch I just got working. Almost 100% based on this "Load-On-Demand" solution:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

I've got the treeView working, but now I need to add something to show and edit data when I select an item in the treeview. 
I imagine it should work like the "regedit", with a treeView on the left, and data on right.

The items in the treeview are not the same, so the data-view needs to change depending on the item selected.

I feel like I have all the handles, but my lack of skills can't put them together. I've tried using the `isSelected` property. but I come shot.

If you guys can give me an idea of what I need to do, I can read up on it.
I think this guy might have the solution I need, but I guess I just don't understand what is going on there:
[WPF TreeView Selected Item and showing User Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338415/wpf-treeview-selected-item-and-showing-user-controls)

This has been my approach so far:

- Creating a EditView UserControl for every TreeItem type
- Depending on the ItemType selected, load the specific `EditView` UserControl in to a GroupBox in the mainwindow.
- I get stuck in some non-static to static errors.

Any advice and pointers is appreciated :)

Comment: What is the exact error you're receiving?

Comment: Hi Oceans

I've created a GroupBox with name="EditAreaGroupBox" in the XAML of the mainwindow.
But when I try to access the GroupBox, I firstly don't get any intellisence on it, and visual writes this:
Cannot access non-static field 'EditAreaGroupBox' in static context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the TreeView's SelectedItemChanged event (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeview.selecteditemchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine when an item selection as occurred. Your approach of showing the corresponding user control for each item sounds correct. In the SelectedItemChanged handler, you can check the type of the item and show the correct user control. You can pass a reference of the underlying item's object to the user control so it can populate its inner controls (textfield, comboboxes, etc).

I am not sure what your non-static to static error is. But a general rule is that static context CAN be used in a non-static context. However, a non-static context CANNOT be used in a static context. Meaning, if you have 2 fields, A (static) and B (non-static); and 2 methods C() (static) and D() (non-static). In method D(), you can use fields A AND B, as well as call method C(). However, in method C() you can only use field A. As long as your code follows those rules, you shouldn't get any static/non-static errors.

Comment: Thanks Tom A

I got passed the point where is was stuck. 

I tried using the SelectedItemChanged handler, instead of using the "INotifyPropertyChanged - isSelected" selected thing. 

Thanks :)